# Ava Testing For Logged In Pages

Tags: testing, nuxt.js, ava

hi i'm new to ava testing. I am able to test for pages that are shown to non logged in users. Now i would like to test for logged in users which means the pages will change accordingly. How do i test for such a scenario? My best guess is to use Phantomjs or nightmarejs with ava.